# Send catch error state from child to parent and show message

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a page  with 2 different containers   that each of them make a data request but if  fails I want replace ALL page  with a big error message in the middle of the page, all blank

If User catch any error, should fail everything and not just show the message where  is, but replace all UserApps code, User and UserProjects will be replaced by the big blank page with error message in the middle

(this is just an example):

**Parent** Component - *UsersApp.tsx*

```
import React, { FC } from "react"
import User from "../containers/User"
import UserProjects from "../containers/UserProjects"

const UsersApp: FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
  {/* //this error must be from child <User/> catch error component */}
  {error ? ( 
          <ErrorState />
        ) : (
            <User />
            <UserProjects />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default UsersApp
```

**Child** Component - User.tsx

```
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { getUserData } from "../requests/getUserData"

const User: FC<{}> = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [age, setAge] = useState("")
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("")

  const getData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setError(false)
    const response = await getUserData()
    const data = response.data
    return data
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
      .then((data) => {
        setName(data.name)
        setAge(data.age)
        setCountry(data.country)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false)
        setError(true)
      })
    return
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <p>{age}</p>
      <p>{country}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default User
```

ErrorState.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

const ErrorState: FC = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Something went wrong!!!!! </h1>
  </div>
)

export default ErrorState
```

Comment: You can move `const [error, setError] = useState(false)` to the parent component, and then you can define a function in your parent component which is responsible for changing the state and pass that function as a prop to the child component. You can call that function when the error is caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent needs to hold the error state. Pass the setError as a prop to the children

```
const UsersApp = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
        {error && <ErrorState/>}
        {!error && (
            <User setError={setError} />
            <UserProjects setError={setError} />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

const User = ({ setError }) => {
  //remove set error state from child
}

const UserProjects = ({ setError }) => {
  //remove set error state from child
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html), it will catch all the errors.