# Regex - Remove special characters but retain negative numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building a Number Stepper component in React which needs to support integers (both positive and negative) and decimal numbers. I want to only hold the numeric part of any possible value in state in order for the arithmetic methods to work correctly.

So:

User enters 5, 5 is stored in state

User enters 5.5, 5.5 is stored in state

User enters £5.57, 5.57 is stored in state

User enters -5, -5 is stored in state

To do this I've been using the following regex within a `.replace()` to remove any special characters:

`value.replace(/[^0-9.]/, '')`

However this removes the minus `-` character from negative values. I have tried adding it to the capture group like this:
`replace(/[^0-9.-]/, '')` but this matches both `-5` and `5 - 3`. I would like to retain negative numbers but exclude any other use of the minus symbol.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You're probably approaching this the wrong way. So, if the user enters something like "1@abc2(d3)_#.z4", you want to interpret that as 123.4? Instead of trying to remove the invalid characters, try to parse the input as a numeric/currency value, and if that fails, tell the user that they need to enter a valid number/price.

Comment: How about `[^0-9.-]+|-\B` (the negated word boundary matches where the word boundary does not match...

Comment: It seems that when users enter a non-valid number, you try to guess, what they mean. I can clearly recommend the comment above, that you should instead tell the user to enter a valid number. That way the user knows what number you're processing.

Comment: I do tend to agree with this sentiment. The problem we have is that our Number Stepper component sits within a Form Item component which handles the displaying of error messages to the user. So the problem becomes how to manage the internal logic of the Number Stepper - for example incrementing or decrementing a value which may contain special characters - whilst also opting to display error messages within a parent component if there's a problem.

Comment: Actually in response to my last comment - this seems to be what we'd need - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010415/send-catch-error-state-from-child-to-parent-and-show-message

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
value.replace(/(-\d*\.?\d+).*|[^0-9.]/g, '')
```

*Details*

- `(?!^)-`  - a hyphen not at the start of string
- `|` - or
- `[^0-9.-]` - any char other than a digit, dot or hyphen.

```js
const c = ['5', '5.5', '£5.57', '-5', '-5-5', '5-3'];
const re = /(?!^)-|[^0-9.-]/g;
for (var i of c) {
    console.log(i, '=>', i.replace(re, ''));
}
```

Comment: This would not trim the second `-` in `-5-5`

Comment: Now it removes the final `-5` whereas mine just removes the `-`...

Not clear if that's what @james-howel wants.

We'll see whose answer gets accepted I guess :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this still allows the user to enter `5-3` for example. I need to only allow minus characters if they are the first character. I'm wondering if I break the validation up into 2 stages. Have something which checks the first character against a regex pattern of numbers, currency symbols or minus character. Then a second part which allows numbers or `.` for the remainder?

Comment: @JamesHowell Please check the update. Only remove `-` that is not at the start of string.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```js
const trimSpecial = x => x
  // first preserve all `-`
  .replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')
  // then remove all `-` except, optionally, the one in first position
  .replace(/(?!^-)-/g, '')

const test = x=>console.log(x, "=>", trimSpecial(x))

test("-5.8")
test("$-3")
test("-5-5")
test("6 - 6")
```